# adb server version (36) doesn't match this client (39) Not using Genymotion. Trying to render react-native project on mobile

Tags: android, react-native

When I try to render react-native project on android mobile i get this error.

```
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 33.858 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Running /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s a258d496 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
adb server version (36) doesn't match this client (39); killing...
* daemon started successfully *
error: closed
Could not run adb reverse: Command failed: /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s a258d496 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on a258d496 (/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s a258d496 shell am start -n com.samplecode/com.samplecode.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.samplecode/.MainActivity }
```

I updated android sdk to latest, still doesn't help. I made sure that only one adb server is running also.

Answer (score 2):

- This is because the adb version on your system is different from the adb version on the android sdk platform-tools.
- Check adb Version:~

  ```
   $adb version
  ```
- Then after

  ```
  $sudo cp ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin
  ```